# Need help identifying insects in home, Morgan Hill CA

Tags: species-identification, entomology

The creature in the attached photos just started appearing in small numbers[image: insect, actual size] in various locations inside my home. Would like to positively identify.

[image: insect, expanded top view][image: insect, expanded underside]

Comment: Yeah, I think you've got it. Lots of farmland around here, and it has been very hot lately (like everywhere else).

Answer (score 2):

This is a [true bug (Heteroptera)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroptera), likely a nymph of the family [Rhyparochromidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyparochromidae). Until recently, this family was part of the Lygaeidea ("seed bugs"). As their colloquial name reveals, they (mostly) feed on seeds (one exception would be the predatory [Geocoridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoris)).

Distinctive characteristics of (almost) all true bugs which are visible on the photos, are the rostrum and the scent glands (which are located dorsally in nymphs and abdominally in adults). The position of the scent glands, thus, indicates that it must be a larvae. Another indication is that its wings are still in pockets.

Determining true bug larvea to the species level is tricky and rarely done. But with some experience, it is possible to tell the families apart. Lygaeid bugs (and thus, also rhyparochromid bugs) are elongated with compact legs and antennas. Often, they have a pointed nose (a long head) and relatively large eyes. All charactericstics match with the specimen on the photo, which makes me think it must be a rhyparochromid bug.

[image: A rhyparochromid nymph]